# Using a C# DLL in Java without 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, c#, dll, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I have a C# dll that I need to use in Java. The dll came with a .chm file that outlined the methods/fields of the classes. After doing research I decided the best way to do it would be to create a C++cli wrapper and use JNI from there to get what I needed to Java.

The way the class is designed to be used is like

```
MyCSharpClass myC = MyCSharpClass.Instance; //Instance is a static field of MyCSharpClass
myC.setState("ON"); // Accepts a string, returns an int
myC.getNetwork(); // Returns a string
```

Instance is a static field, and the two method calls there return int.

I was trying to base my wrapper off of the example here: http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/

I have no issue with using JNI to call into the C++cli DLL from Java, except for when I try to instantiate the class instance from C# in C++cli the JVM crashes.

```
_private->myCSharpClass= gcnew MyDLL::MyCSharpClass();
```

Does not work because the class has no constructor and

```
_private->myCSharpClass= MyDLL::MyCSharpClass::Instance;
```

does not work either.

I am pretty lost on what do to. I have read post and examples for hours without any real success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific on why the `myCSharpClass= MyDLL::MyCSharpClass::Instance;` does not work?

Comment: When I instantiate MyCSharpClassWrapper to use in a JNI method, the call in Java causes the JVM to crash. I cannot remember the exact message it says.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Instance` member is a property and not a field, could you try the following way?

```
_private->myCSharpClass= MyDLL::MyCSharpClass::get_Instance()
```

In C# properties are in fact methods.

Comment: I am fairly certain I tried that with no avail. I was going to try, then had a grave realization. I cannot remote into my workstation because it is shutdown, and my team members on are vacation.